# wp_nav_menu prints children with parent name

Tags: php, sub-menu, menus

This code

```
echo wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 'depth' => '2', 'echo' => false ) );
```

prints

```
Parent
- Parent
- Parent
- Parent
```

instead of:

```
Parent
- Child 1
- Child 2
- Child 3
```

How can I print the menu with correct children names?

Answer (score 0):

[wp_nav_menu](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) displays the menu created in the **Appearences > Menu** section of wordpress admin area. That is where you can "print the menu with correct children names".

Unless there is some other code in your functions that is messing with the wp_nav_menu function.

Comment: yes I know that. If I call `wp_nav_menu` outside the element `<nav id="main_menu">` it works, but the problem is when I call it inside that element. I can't get what's the issue

Comment: If its only happening when in a certain container, then that makes me think it could be css or js effecting it. Could you perhaps link to the site? Or provide any other information.

Comment: Yeah Nath, that was it! It was a JS that change some html... thanks.